# Can't explore java.util, java.time or java.lang packages (rt.jar) with JD-GUI newer versions

Tags: jd-gui

JD-GUI below version 0.3.2 are able to explore these packages, but all versions above 0.3.1 to 0.3.7 RC1 giving this error (either exploring from left tree-view window or using Ctrl+Shift+T):

**"An unhandled exception occured. Press "Abort" to terminate the program, "Retry" to exit the program normally and "Ignore" to try to continue."**

Can anyone share links where I can download jd-gui below version 0.3.

Comment: Why do you need to explore those packages with a decompiler? The JDK is open-source; you can go read the actual source code with comments, proper variable names etc.

Comment: @yole Oh, Thanks, didn't even think about this.